HTTPS POST Request with insecure (not encoded) client HTTP 400 with apache, not with nginx
I have an old device that I can't update. These clients request a web with a POST request.
They can't handle SSL certificate so the request on my HTTPS server is made no encoded (the data are not personal)
When these clients make the POST request :

On my personnal nginx server, no problem, the POST return a 200 HTTP Code.
On my future apache server, the same client have a 400 HTTP Error code in return.

The only change I made is the DNS so my old device reach the new or the old server, so I think my apache setting need something to avoid these errors
Here is my nginx conf :
server {

server_name xxxxxxxxxxxxx;

root /var/www/html/xxxxxxxx; 

index index.php;

client_max_body_size 100M;


access_log /var/log/nginx/xxxxxxxx_access.log;

error_log /var/log/nginx/xxxxxx_error.log;


location ~ \.php$ {

include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

fastcgi_send_timeout 600;

fastcgi_read_timeout 600;

}


location ~ ^/api/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) {

 try_files $uri $uri/ /api.php?controlleur=$1&arg1=$2&arg2=$3;

}


location ~ ^/api/(.*)/(.*) {

try_files $uri $uri/ /api.php?controlleur=$1&arg1=$2;

}


location ~ ^/api/(.*) {

try_files $uri $uri/ /api.php?controlleur=$1;

}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxx/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxx/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

My .htaccess apache config file :`
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /api.php?controlleur=$1&arg1=$2&arg2=$3 [L,B]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)/(.*)$ /api.php?controlleur=$1&arg1=$2 [L,B]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /api.php?controlleur=$1 [L,B]``

`
Anyone knows which setting I can use to avoid the 400 http error code send by apache server ?
